# Analytic expression of the root of $f(x)+c=0$ for a strictly increasing, surjective, analytic function, vanishing at $x=0$ only

Tags: analysis, elementary-functions

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an analytic, strictly increasing, surjective function that vanishes only at $x=0$.

Is there any way to compute the real root of $f(x)+c=0$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ analytically? (It is obvious that $f(x)+c=0$ has only one real root).

Is it always possible to express the root of $f(x)+c=0$ in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: it is analytic function.

Comment: if it has a closed form, I accept it :|)

Comment: Please state your additional assumptions in the text of your question as well that others get informed of the content of the question correctly.

Comment: @stressed-out thank you for thinking about my question

Comment: No, I will be grateful if you have any suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69906/discussion-between-p-kn-and-stressed-out).

Answer (score 1):

By your assumptions, $f(x)=-c$, $f$ is a surjective, strictly increasing, analytic function on all of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0 \implies x=0$.

Therefore, $f$ has a convergent infinite series everywhere and by the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), if $f'(-c) \neq 0$, $x=f^{-1}(-c)$ can be expressed as an infinite series:

${\displaystyle x=-c+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }g_{n}{\frac {(z-f(-c))^{n}}{n!}},}$ where ${\displaystyle g_{n}=\lim _{w\to -c}\left[{\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{\,n-1}}{\mathrm {d} w^{\,n-1}}}\left({\frac {w+c}{f(w)-f(-c)}}\right)^{n}\right]}$

This settles down the issue of expressing the root of $f(x)+c=0$ analytically when $f'(-c) \neq 0$. The problem of whether $f^{-1}(x)$ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions is rather subtle and I have obtained partial results on this. I haven't found a counter-example yet, but I have found several examples and a class of functions for which it is possible.

Comment: thanks, let f be a polynomial of degree n, what we can say in this case about the root.

Comment: It's not true, under the hypotheses that $f'(-c)\ne0$ for every $c$. Think to $f(x)=x^3$ which satisfies the hypotheses, but $f'(0)=0$. For another example, $f(x)=x-\sin x$, whose derivative vanishes at infinitely many points.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for pointing it out. :)